# How to draw a Venn diagram of 6 sets using ZingChart?

Tags: javascript, zingchart, venn-diagram

I want to draw a Venn diagram of 6 sets. Is it possible by using ZingChart?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to draw a venn diagram with 6 circles in Zingchart. This is also the case with other charting libraries. The reasoning is to get the math perfect with more than 3 circles is very complex.